# Does etherjs TransactionReceipt have an events object?

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat

In tutorials and stackoverflow answers it is common to see code that reads emitted event data like this:

```
let someTx = await contractRef.someFunc();
let txReceipt = await someTx.wait(1);

let eventData = txReceipt.events[0].topics[0]  
// or txReceipt.events[0].args.someData.toString()
```

Two questions:

1. How is the events object getting added to TransactionReceipt? The [etherjs docs](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/single-page/#/v5/api/providers/types/-%23-providers-TransactionReceipt) on TransactionReceipt dont include an events object. It only includes a `logs` property.
2. what the difference between `events[0].topics` and `events[0].args`?

**UPDATE ON QUESTION 1**

Still researching, but the ethers source shows the following:
interface Event extends Log ([ref](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/blob/master/packages/contracts/src.ts/index.ts#L75))  and interface TransactionReceipt has an array of Log ([ref](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/blob/master/packages/abstract-provider/src.ts/index.ts#L106))
Event is a child of Log, so it implements the same interface as Log but there is still no property on TxReceipt that is called events.

So ethersjs' docs are consistent with the source.

Next question is how a property called `events` gets added to the `TransactionReceipt` interface.

Answer (score 3):

The ethers docs are misleading, as discussed [here](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/discussions/2207):

> The events property is only available on a ContractReceipt (see the docs), as a normal receipt does not have access to the ABI.

Therefore, instead of expecting in this case `TransactionResponse` and `TransactionReceipt`, use the interfaces `ContractTransaction` and `ContractReceipt`.

Like:

```
const txResponse : ContractTransaction = await contract.method();
const txReceipt : ContractReceipt = await txResponse.wait();
```

Comment: @ZeusLawyer happy if I could help you on this.

Comment: Didn't know about `ContractTransaction` and `ContractReceipt`. Super helpful, thanks!